# "Cannot find -lallegro-5.0.4-monolith-mt" Error in Dev-C++ with Allegro

Tags: c++, linker, find, dev-c++, allegro

So I downloaded the latest version of Orwell Dev-C++ and managed to run basic text based C++ programs. I downloaded the Allegro 5.0.4 Devpak and installed it using packman.exe. But whenever I try to run code with

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
```

in the header, I get this error...

```
Cannot find -lallegro-5.0.4-monolith-mt
```

I'm using the default Allegro example template so there can't be an error in the syntax. I've looked everywhere on the internet for an answer to my problem, but I haven't been able to find anything. I've tried adding links, and including different folders in the Compiler Options under Directories, but no luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this error or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using 64-bit Orwell Dev-C++ instead of 32-bit.